# Java syntax error tokens

Tags: java, syntax, token

```
package test;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("            _______________\n");
    System.out.println("   .--H--.|                 |\n");
    System.out.println(" _//_||  ||    Παγωτά       |\n");
    System.out.println("[    -|  |'--;--------------'\n ");
    System.out.println("  '-()-()----()"()^^^^^^^()"()' ");

}
}
```

I have this but i have a problem at:

```
System.out.println("  '-()-()----()"()^^^^^^^()"()' ");
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Syntax error on token ""  \'-()-()----()"", invalid Name
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

at test.test.main(test.java:11)
```

Can anyone help me?? how i solve the prob??

Comment: Notice even how the code formatting above changes the text color when it reaches the first close quote since it is not escaped.

Answer (score 2):

`"` is special in Java, because it represents start or end of String. If you want to print it you need to escape it with `\"`, so use

```
System.out.println("  '-()-()----()\"()^^^^^^^()\"()' ");
```

Also you don't need `\n` at the end of your Strings since you are printing each line using `println` which adds line separator after printed String for you.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes `"` are special characters. You need to escape them when they appear within `String`  literals.

```
"\""
```